# Blob download is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs, blob, compatibility

I have this in my Angular.js controller that downloads a CSV file:

```js
 var blob = new Blob([csvContent.join('')], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'});
 var link = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'a');
 link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 link.download = 'teams.csv';
 link.click();
```

This works perfectly in Chrome but not in IE. A browser console log says:

> HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for
>   which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data
>   backing the URL has been freed.

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem in IE with `parallel.js`.

Comment: could you help me modifying my snippet the way you specified.
http://jsfiddle.net/9gct9u78/

Answer (score 82):

Try this using, `this` or `useragent`

```
if (navigator.appVersion.toString().indexOf('.NET') > 0)
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
else
{
 var blob = new Blob(['stringhere'], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8' });
 var link = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'a');
 link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 link.download = 'teams.csv';
 link.click();
}
```

Comment: +1. But to make it work in Firefox I had to add : `document.body.appendChild(link);` before the `click()` - and then remove the link again !

Comment: @PierreHenry
or you make the link invisible by 
`link.setAttribute('style','display:none');`

Comment: It's not recommend to rely on navigator.appVersion (@see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/appVersion)

I would recommend to modify the if-statement to this:


`if (typeof(window.navigator.msSaveBlob) == 'function'){....`

Answer (score 55):

IE won't allow you to open blobs directly. You have to use `msSaveOrOpenBlob`. There's also `msSaveBlob`

```
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
} else {
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(objectUrl);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, This worked for me. I can now download the PDF in both Chrome and IE. ++1

Comment: Perfect !! Worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

I needed to use a Blob to download a converted a base64 PNG image. I was able to successfully download the blob on IE11 with `window.navigator.msSaveBlob`

See the following msdn link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx

Specifically, you should call:

```
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blobObject, 'msSaveBlob_testFile.txt');
```

where `blobObject` is a Blob created in the usual fashion.

Comment: or then for saving or opening the file in IE 11 or Egde: window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'filename.pdf');

Answer (score 11):

#### Complete Solution for Chrome, Internet Explorer Firefox and Opera

*There are lots of nice bits on this page, but I had to use a combination of a few things to get it all to work. Hopefully this helps you.*

1. Use a button or link to trigger a function called `download()`:

```html
<button class="button-no save-btn" ng-click="download()">DOWNLOAD</button>
```

2. Put this in your controller:

```js
$scope.download = function () {

    // example shows a JSON file
    var content = JSON.stringify($scope.stuffToPutInFile, null, "  ");
    var blob = new Blob([content], {type: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'});

    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {

        // Internet Explorer workaround
        $log.warn("Triggering download using msSaveBlob");
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, "export.json");

    } else {
        
        // other browsers
        $log.warn("Triggering download using webkit");
        var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
        
        // create invisible element
        var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
        downloadLink.attr('href', url);
        downloadLink.attr('download', 'export.json');
        
        // make link invisible and add to the DOM (Firefox)
        downloadLink.attr('style','display:none');
        angular.element(document.body).append(downloadLink);
        
        // trigger click
        downloadLink[0].click();
    }
};
```

Comment: This worked awesome for mein IE, chrome, firefox and edge, thank you

Answer (score 1):

What's your IE browser version? You need a modern browser or IE10+ 
http://caniuse.com/bloburls

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need some delay. What about with:

```
link.click();
setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'a');
    URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);  
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to get the download feature to work in Chrome and IE11.  I had good success with this code.

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="attachment in attachments">
  <a ng-click="openAttachment(attachment)" ng-href="{{attachment.fileRef}}">{{attachment.filename}}</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.openAttachment = function (attachment) {
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(
      b64toBlob(attachment.attachment, attachment.mimeType),
      attachment.filename
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Done it this way, working fine for me.

```
downloadFile(data) {
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      let blob = new Blob([data], {
        "type": "text/csv;charset=utf8;"
      });
      navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, this.fileName);
    }
    else {
      let blob = new Blob(['\ufeff' + data], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
      let $link = document.createElement("a");
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      $link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
      $link.setAttribute("href", url);
      $link.setAttribute("download", this.fileName);
      $link.style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.body.appendChild($link);
      $link.click();
      document.body.removeChild($link);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead :
var blob = file.slice(0, file.size);

Comment: See this Question / answser:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206127/createobjecturl-does-not-work-in-ie10

Answer (score 0):

Create polyfill method as below,had a variable filename since in my case download filename was static.This method will be called while blob function is not supported as in case of Internet explorer

```
    if (!HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob) {
            Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 
            'toBlob', {
                value: function (callback, type, quality) {
                var canvas = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                var binStr = atob(canvas.toDataURL(type, quality).split(',')[1]),
                    len = binStr.length,
                    arr = new Uint8Array(len);

                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
                }
                var blob = new Blob([arr], {
                    type: 'image/png'
                });
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
      const blob = new Blob([res.body], {
        type: res.headers.get('Content-Type'),
      });
      const file = new File([blob], this.getFileName(res), {
        type: res.headers.get('Content-Type'),
      });

      saveAs(file);
    } catch (err) {
      var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([res.body], {
        type: res.headers.get('Content-Type'),
      });
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(textFileAsBlob, this.getFileName(res));
    }
```

To get the file name. Use the below function.

```
getFileName(response: any) {
    let name: string;
    try {
      const contentDisposition: string = response.headers.get(
        'content-disposition'
      );
      const [, filename] = contentDisposition.split('filename=');
      name = filename;
    } catch (e) {
      name = 'File_Name_Not_Specified_' + new Date();
    }
    return name;
  }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: new File() constructor is not working on iE11. is there any alternative solution for this ? to convert a blob file to File() type without using File constructor on IE11.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39329659/8437877. Also check for other browser compatibility using this https://caniuse.com/?search=file.

Comment: It was mentioned there to download or save file to local but what I need is to send that file to API request in File type format. just wondering is that actually possible on IE11 ?