# Download current jsp (html) file in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, internet-explorer

we are using following solution for downloading current page, but this solution doesn't work in IE11.

```
<a download="view.html" onclick="this.href='data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML)" href="#">Download</a>
```

Is it possible to have similiar solution which works in IE11?

Comment: Similar question: [blob download not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310688/blob-download-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: No, it's not similar.

Comment: You need to use [msSaveBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  As noted in the similar question, IE does not have a download attribute. See [chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)