# Angular 5 download document via anchor not working in IE

Tags: javascript, angular, authorization, angular5, anchor

My website has some documents that are only "download-able" if they are logged in. So when an `anchor` element gets clicked, it needs to append the `authorization` header, then the API returns the `blob`. In order to add the authorization header, I used the solution where I replace the `href` on the `anchor` element with a `click` event. Here's that code:

Html

```
<a class="{{ anchorClasses }}" (click)="!downloadDocument(path)" href="">
    <i *ngIf="iconClasses && iconClasses.length > 0" class="{{ iconClasses }}" aria-hidden="true"></i><span [innerHTML]="linkText"></span>
</a>
```

Typescript code

```
downloadDocument(url: string) {
    this.appDataService.spinnerService.show();

    return this.anchorDocumentService.downloadDocument(url)
        .subscribe((result: any) => {
            this.downloadFileFromBlob(result, url);

            return false;
        }, (error: any) => {
            console.error(error);

            this.appDataService.spinnerService.hide();
            this.appDataService.routeToErrorPage(error);

            return false;
        });
}
```

As you'll see in the subscribe's function success callback, I immediately call the "downloadFileFromBlob" function, here's that:

```
private downloadFileFromBlob(blob: any, url?: string) {
    console.log('DownloadLinkComponent | downloadFileFromBlob...');

    try {
        const anchorDownloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const anchorDownload = document.createElement('a');

        document.body.appendChild(anchorDownload);

        anchorDownload.href = anchorDownloadUrl;

        anchorDownload.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
        anchorDownload.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

        if (url && url.length > 0) {
            anchorDownload.setAttribute('download', this.isDocumentService.getFilenameFromPath(url));
        }

        console.log('DownloadLinkComponent | downloadFileFromBlob | clicking the hidden download link...');
        anchorDownload.click();
        // anchorDownload.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window }));

        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(anchorDownloadUrl);
    } catch (error) {
        this.appDataService.routeToErrorPage(error);
    } finally {
        this.appDataService.spinnerService.hide();
    }
}
```

So, in `chrome`, this works great. But in IE, it's throwing an error on this line:

```
anchorDownload.click();
```

In IE, the error page that is displayed says:

> The webpage cannot be displayed
>
> ```
>  Most likely cause: •Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed.
> ```

Here's where I got the code to add the auth header: [How to set a header for a HTTP GET request, and trigger file download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501358/how-to-set-a-header-for-a-http-get-request-and-trigger-file-download/24523253#24523253)

So, in `chrome` when that click event fires, it downloads the blob to my local file system, and the `url`, aka filepath for that file is what is set as the `href` for the [hidden] anchor click event. So....why is IE not able to download this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this should be closed, or just a link to the answer...so here's a link to the answer that I found:

[blob download not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310688/blob-download-not-working-in-ie)

The fix for this is just two lines of code:

```
if (navigator.appVersion.toString().indexOf('.NET') > 0)
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
else
        const anchorDownloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const anchorDownload = document.createElement('a');
        // ... the rest of the code in the 'downloadFileFromBlog' function
```

So, just a quick check to see if we are running in IE, if so, just call the save function.